Chrome blocks file download - selenium
I've been using webdriver selenium 3.12 and chromedriver for Chrome 125.
I have put in arguments and capabilities everything that I found on internet, yet my xml file gets blocked as insecure, by chrome when run.
Run is not headless.
Currently I have added this parameters to webdriver:
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", savePAth);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", false);
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
chromePrefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[]{"Adobe Flash Player", "Chrome PDF Viewer"});
chromePrefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "en");
chromePrefs.put("download_restrictions", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.extensions_to_open", "xml");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("--disable-application-cache");
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--lang=en");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--disable-password-manager");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
options.addArguments("--disable-features=InsecureDownloadWarnings");
options.addArguments("--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure={url}");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");


I have added
options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
and
changed
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
and it worked.
